# Divs position change when changing screen width

Tags: html, css

I am trying to design something like this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXBRC.png). Two divs don't stay properly when I change browser width. If I give two divs `float:left`, they stay vertically, but its broken when I change screen size.

How can I keep divs together and inside border like in the picture?

```css
ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}

ol .search-result {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    min-height: 220px;
    color: #000;
    padding: 10px 5px;
}

.media-box {
    float: left;
}

.search-result-item {
    overflow: auto;
    max-width: 600px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
}

.search-item-box {
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    min-height: 226px;
    transition: box-shadow .2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.search-item-box:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 14px 13px 20px -9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);
    -moz-box-shadow: 14px 13px 20px -9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);
    box-shadow: 14px 13px 20px -9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);
}

.item-price-promo-container {
    padding: 5px;
    width: 180px;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 350px;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<ol id="searchListContainer" class="search-list-container">
<li class="search-result">
    <a id="hotel-id" class="search-result-item" href="#" target="_blank">
        <section class="search-item-box">
            <div class="media-box">
                <figure class="media">
                    <img src="https://s15.postimg.org/7w2xbeufv/image.jpg" height="225"
                         width="225"
                         alt="1.jpg"/>
                </figure>
            </div>
            <div class="item-price-promo-container">
                <div class="item-review-container">
                    <ul class="item-star-rate">
                        <li class="item-star-rate-container review-item">
                            <strong class="item-star-rate-symbol">&#9733;</strong>
                            <strong class="item-star-rate-number">3.5</strong>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </a>
</li>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use `%`instead of `px`for the widths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify things a lot here by using **CSS Flexbox**.

Let's say you want to horizontally split each `li` into three sections.

- You want the **first section** to be `225px` wide. When the page width changes, you don't want it to grow bigger than that, you don't want it to shrink smaller than that: `flex: 0 0 225px;`
- You want the **last section** to be `325px` wide. When the page width changes, you don't want it to grow bigger than that, you don't want it to shrink smaller than that: `flex: 0 0 325px;`
- You want the **middle section** to fill the horizontal gap between the first and last sections. You don't mind if it grows bigger (as the page widens) and you don't mind if it shrinks smaller (as the page narrows): `flex: 1 1 calc(100% - 550px);`

**Working Example:**

```css
ol {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

li {
display: flex;
height: 100px;
margin-bottom: 6px;
border: 1px solid rgb(227,227,227);
list-style-type: none;
}

li div:nth-of-type(1) {
flex: 0 0 225px;
background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
}

li div:nth-of-type(2) {
flex: 1 1 calc(100% - 550px);
background-color: rgb(255,255,0);
}

li div:nth-of-type(3) {
flex: 0 0 325px;
background-color: rgb(0,127,0);
}
```

```html
<ol>
<li>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</li>

<li>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</li>

<li>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detail explanation. It helps me to understand better.

Comment: You're most welcome @DianaJ - CSS Flexbox has been a long time evolving but in 2016 it is now evolved and works in all browsers. I held off learning it for a long time (I didn't want to learn it when it still only had limited browser support) but since I learned it (this summer!) I haven't looked back. This is the website I used to learn it (it's fantastic!): http://flexboxfroggy.com/

Answer (score 0):

First of all you forgot the closing </ol> tag.

If you want to keep the divs floating you can use percent widths or **display: table** and **display: table-cell**
Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/edtyv9tr/1

The new CSS:

```
ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}

ol .search-result {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 10px 5px;
}

.media-box {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 225px;
}

.media-box img {
    vertical-align: middle; /* Remove spacing below image */
}

.media {
    margin: 0; /* Remove natural padding around the figure tag */
}

.search-result-item {
    max-width: 600px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
}

.search-item-box {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    transition: box-shadow .2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.search-item-box:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 14px 13px 20px -9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);
    -moz-box-shadow: 14px 13px 20px -9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);
    box-shadow: 14px 13px 20px -9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);
}

.item-price-promo-container {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```